# How do you make a hold note like in FNF

Tags: godot

I want to make a longnote like in the game Friday Night Funkin.

If you don't know FNF this is the long notes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXZ5Zmnk6Yg

Code:

```
if (Input.is_action_pressed("up")) or (Input.is_action_pressed("down")) or (Input.is_action_pressed("right")) or (Input.is_action_pressed("left")):
        mouseheld = true
    else:
        mouseheld = false
    if (isLongNote == true) and (Input.is_action_just_pressed("up") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == 0) or (Input.is_action_just_pressed("down") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == -180) or (Input.is_action_just_pressed("right") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == 90) or (Input.is_action_just_pressed("left") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == -90):
        createAEffect()
        print(mouseheld)
        if mouseheld == false:
            Singletons.bad()
            queue_free()
        print(mouseheld)
        # COMMENT HERE
        if mouseheld == true:
            print('rlly good')
            Singletons.sick()
            queue_free()
        else:
            print('...')
            Singletons.good()
            queue_free()
```

The problem is at where I put a comment, I tried to put a yield function (basically wait a second and see if the mouse is still held) but the yield function (yield(get_tree().create_timer(1)), "timeout") didn't work (for some reason doesnt work inside of a function)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a system like this

```
if holdNote > time:
        print('t')
        holdNote = 0
        holdTheNote = false
        Singletons.sick()
    if holdTheNote == true:
        holdNote += delta
    if holdTheNote == true and ((Input.is_action_pressed("up") == false and sprite.rotation_degrees == 0) or (Input.is_action_pressed("down") == false and sprite.rotation_degrees == -180) or (Input.is_action_pressed("right") == false and sprite.rotation_degrees == 90) or (Input.is_action_pressed("left") == false and sprite.rotation_degrees == -90)):
        if holdNote < (time * 0.75):
            print('t2')
            Singletons.bad()
        if holdNote >= (time * 0.75):
            print('t32')
            Singletons.good()
        holdTheNote = false
        holdNote = 0
    if (isLongNote == true) and (Input.is_action_just_pressed("up") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == 0) or (Input.is_action_just_pressed("down") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == -180) or (Input.is_action_just_pressed("right") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == 90) or (Input.is_action_just_pressed("left") and touching == true and sprite.rotation_degrees == -90):
        createAEffect()
        holdTheNote = true
```